# Calculate AUC of a logistic regression model

Tags: regression, logistic, roc, auc

I have a data sample of a bank loan history of customers. I have performed logistic regression testing on the sample for finding out how the loan repayment(YES/NO) is dependent on various factors. I have verified the model using the chi-square test. But in various websites I see questions like 'What is the AUC of the model?' I was able to find out that it stands for area under the ROC curve. Can anyone please throw some light on this on how to find AUC of the model (preferably in R)?

Comment: Answer [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/80399/can-someone-sort-me-out-regarding-the-calculation-of-auc/80404#80404).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am unable to download package pROC on R 3.0.2. Has the package been removed?

Comment: You're welcome. I've no idea if pROC has been removed (from CRAN presumably) - you don't need it anyway for the AUC calculation given in the linked answer.